# JSON prints twice from PHP API when DB

Tags: php, json

My API is fetching a single row from a MySQL table, encoding it to JSON, and echoing it. I am using the distinct query to prevent duplicates, but the JSON includes each value twice.

My query fetches data like this

[image: DB Screenshot]

Here's the JSON that I am getting:

[image]

My PHP API code is:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "testuser";
$password = "dbpassword";
$dbname = "testDB";

// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT BANK FROM BANK_MASTER";


$response = array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $response[] = $row;
    }

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php - don't fetch as both and you'll only get one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Problem

The problem is in how you call [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). By default, if you omit the second parameter, `mysqli_fetch_array` fetches data using the `MYSQLI_BOTH` type (see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)). That means it returns both numeric and column-name keys. So, if your data is like this:

```
BANK
--------
ABC Bank
DEF Bank
```

You will get an array for each row like this:

```
array(
    0 => "ABC Bank",
    "BANK" => "ABC Bank"
)
```

That will produce JSON like

```
[
    {
        "0":"ABC Bank",
        "BANK":"ABC Bank"
    },
    {
        "0":"DEF Bank",
        "BANK":"DEF Bank"
    }
]
```

## The Solution

Use a result type of `MYSQLI_ASSOC` or `MYSQLI_NUM` instead, as in

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

or

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
```

## Some Additional Advice

You really should add some error-checking code to handle database errors. Also, you are mixing functional code like `mysqli_fetch_array()` with object-oriented code like `$conn->close()`. This will work if you are careful, but it is not a very good practice and leads to more errors. It also makes testing much, much harder. I'd strongly recommend using only one or the other, and personally I would go with object-oriented code, hands-down.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array):

> Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, **or both**

and (pay attention to the default value for the final argument!):

> ```
> mixed mysqli_result::fetch_array ([ int $resulttype = MYSQLI_BOTH ] )
> ```

… so provide a different value for the result type:

> This optional parameter is a constant indicating what type of array should be produced from the current row data. The possible values for this parameter are the constants MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, or MYSQLI_BOTH.